# Python error in opening image with PIL Image.Open()

Tags: python, image, import, package, python-imaging-library

I am trying to do some studies and automation related to image metadata.

```
from PIL import Image

Image.open("/Users/carlo/Desktop/JPEG 2/DSC_0393.jpeg")
```

This is the error that I am receiving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/carlo/PythonProjects/ImageMetaData_00/main.py", line 1, in <module>
from PIL import Image
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 114, in <module>
from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-310-darwin.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-310-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-310-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

I am using Python 3.10, not sure what I am missing. Thanks!

Comment: Move your file into your project folder and rename the path in your code accordingly.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help.

still not working from here:
Tried both
Image.open("DSC_0393.jpeg")
&
Image.open("/Users/carlo/PythonProjects/ImageMetaData_0/DSC_0393.jpeg")

Same error persists.

Answer (score 0):

It’s telling you you’ve got a version of PIL downloaded/installed, but it’s not suitable for your computer architecture. You’re probably on an M1 Mac instead of an Intel one. To fix this try these:

- `pip3 install wheel`
- `pip3 install --no-cache-dir pillow`

If that doesn't work, you can try to switch to using python via Rosetta.

> Go to the Application folder -> Right-click on Terminal App -> Get Info

> Tick Open with Rosetta option.

Also try reinstalling it: `pip3 install pillow`.

If all else fails try downgrading python and see if anything clicks.